# How to edit a record in java text file?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a text file which have contents like this:

```
    1 John 200
    4 Jack 144
    7 Sarah 123
```

the programming format of this record is

```
     int id, String name, int quantity
```

My question is how to edit record like this:

```
Enter id of the record you want to edit?
1
New Name:
Terry
New Quantity:
700
```

so after doing this the file must be like this:

```
    1 Terry 700
    4 Jack 144
    7 Sarah 123
```

but I am stuck in this code because I am still a java beginner?

Comment: Read your file. Create a new object for each line then stock it in a List or something. Edit the object and write everything back.

Comment: Easiest if the file isn't too big is to read it completely into an in-memory list. You can use a Scanner or similar. Then modify the list and write it out again.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer you should choose another nick name: "Beginner Manager". Programmers write programs by themselves. It's OK to ask for help, but if all you want is someone doing the job for you, that's not programming anymore. Voting to close.

Comment: well, Iam sorry you can close the question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code. Let me know if you need explanation :D

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanFile {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        String newName=null;
        String newQuantity=null;
        boolean checked = true;

     File f= new File("E:\\myFile.txt");          // path to your file
     File tempFile = new File("E:\\myTempFile.txt"); // create a temp file in same path
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
     System.out.println("Enter id of the record you want to edit?");
     Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
     int id = sc2.nextInt();
     while(sc.hasNextLine())
     {
         String currentLine= sc.nextLine();
         String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
         if(Integer.valueOf(tokens[0])==id && checked)
         {
             sc2.nextLine();                          
             System.out.println("New Name:");
             newName= sc2.nextLine();
             System.out.println("New Quantity:");
             newQuantity= sc2.nextLine();
             currentLine = tokens[0]+" "+newName+" "+newQuantity;
             checked = false;
         }
         writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

     }
     writer.close(); 
     sc.close();
     f.delete();
     boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Completing others' homework assignments for them is both a waste of your time and theirs, and goes against Stack Overflow's principles of **assisting** users to find the answers **themselves**.

Comment: Ok.I'll keep this in mind from now. Thank you.